# Simplifying this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

How can I simplify the following matrix equation?

$$\frac{||A \times B||_{II}}{||A||_{II}}$$

where `A, B` are `3x1` matrices, `x` is a cross product.

EDIT: I'm askingg about the cross product in **3D** space and using the usual **Euclidean** norm.

[the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1KhJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please confirm that that you're asking about the [cross product in 3D space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition) and you're using the usual Euclidean norm?

Comment: To call the vectors $\;A,\,B\;$ "matrices", in this particular case, was irrelevant and confusing...and what is that "II" as index of the norm?

Comment: Check out how the norm of a cross product can be expressed in terms of the norms of the individual vectors, and the angle between them. I agree - the phrasing of the problem is...confusing, so I'm doing a bit of mind-reading here.

Comment: @Ertxiem I'm sorry that it was unclear. You're correct.

Comment: @Ertxiem I see, so is it correct that the answer is ||B||_{II} * sin(Theta) then?

Comment: @AlexKorzunov Yes, that is correct...but I'm not sure if that is "simplifying"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation is odd

$$ \frac{\| A \times B \|}{\| A\|} = \frac{\|A\|\|B\| \sin(\theta)}{\|A\| } = \|B\| \sin(\theta)$$